# Why is my loop outputting two different results?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting, iteration

I need help with the following code. After iterating a random array userArray_Copy through this loop, the first two results of nanoseconds are consistently different from the rest of the results. I have no idea why.
Here is the full code through a pastebin file.
https://pastebin.com/S2YWp8Gh
I have been stuck on this problem for hours now, any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
do{
  //Resetting array and time
  for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
      userArray_Copy[i] = userArray[i];
  }
  stopwatch.reset();
  elapsedTime = 0;
  stopwatch.start();
  bubbleSort(userArray_Copy, n);
  stopwatch.stop();
  elapsedTime = stopwatch.getElapsedTime();
  stopwatch.reset();
  System.out.println("\nSORTED ARRAY");
  for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
      System.out.print(userArray_Copy[i]+" ");
  }

  System.out.println("\nTime taken in nanoseconds: "+elapsedTime+"\n\nRun Algorithm against unsorted array again?[Y/N]");
  char A = reader.next().charAt(0);
  if(A == ('y')||(A == 'Y')){
      runAgain=true;
  }
  else {
    runAgain=false;
    System.out.println("Average time of sorting algorithm: "+stopwatch.getElapsedTime()+"\nNumber of algorithms completed: "+AverageRuns);
  }
}while(runAgain);
```

```
static void bubbleSort(int[] userArray_Copy, int n) {

      int temp;
      for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
         for (int j = 0 ; j < n-1 ; j++)
         {

            if ( userArray_Copy[j] > userArray_Copy[j+1] )
            {
               temp = userArray_Copy[j];
               userArray_Copy[j] = userArray_Copy[j+1];
               userArray_Copy[j+1] = temp;

            }
         }
   }
```

```
public class StopWatch
{
   private long elapsedTime;
   private long startTime;
   private boolean isRunning;

   public StopWatch()
{
      reset();
   }
   public void start()
   {
      if (isRunning)
         return;
      isRunning = true;
      startTime = System.nanoTime();
   }
   public void stop()
   {
      if(!isRunning)
         return;
      isRunning = false;
      long endTime = System.nanoTime();
      elapsedTime = endTime-startTime;
   }
   public long getElapsedTime()
   {
      if(isRunning)
      {
         long endTime = System.nanoTime();
         elapsedTime = (endTime-startTime);
         return elapsedTime;
      }
      else
         return elapsedTime;
   }
   public void reset()
   {
      elapsedTime = 0;
      isRunning = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because java.

This is not how you time things in java.

Use the [JMH framework](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to time code in java.

Here's what's probably happening*: Java runs code very slowly out of the box: It is simply interpreting bytecode (which is not much more efficient than java source code is), and spending a lot of extra time doing some basic bookkeeping on these runs to boot.

That's because this is irrelevant: For the vast majority of apps, 99% of the CPU and memory resources are used up by 1% of your codebase. If you can optimize that 1%, the app is incredibly fast. So that 1% is all that matters, and optimizing that well, is all that matters.

Which is precisely what java does: Once it realizes (through that bookkeeping I mentioned) that the bulk of this VM's time is spent on this sorting code, it'll freeze out the code for a bit, use its extensive bookkeeping about which way branches tend to go, which conditions always seem to hold, etc – to produce highly tuned specialized branch-predicted optimized machine code written juust so. And once it's done that, it'll then use this highly optimized version. At least, until one of the seemingly always true preconditions baked into the code ceases to be true, in which case the optimized code is invalidated, java would fall back to the slow interpreted way of doing it, until it is again time to produce an optimized version.

*) And that is just one of a great many ways java optimizes and runs differently. From garbage collection to hotspot compilation, there are many many ways which modify runtimes like this. I've even quite oversimplified the above!

Comment: So for the very second time of every pass I do through the bubble sort algorithm. without fail, only the second time is off?